# Block with Php side for EASY APNS

Tags: php, mysql, apple-push-notifications

Sorry because I'm pretty bad in PHP

Thus I find myself very very stupidly blocked because I am unable to understand or I have to put my info to my connections in my database file "class_DbConnect.php"

in case the file looks like this:

https://github.com/manifestinteractive/easyapns/blob/master/src/php/classes/class_DbConnect.php ...

So I tried to resolve it myself by watching the video of "demo" but it is obsolette. The php file taken from the demo being different, at least different enough to trouble me!

I am sure it is simple : I have 4 informations (host, username, pass and DB name) but i don't know where to set them in the file ... i know it's in this file but don't know where.

For the rest, we will see later. I have created the necessary DB, I must also understand how the certificates, how to recover, etc. ... but for now, I should like already done with the php part ...

I will post the different findings and actions here ... I'm pretty sure it will be usefull for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not to put the information in the file but add them when you declare the class

Explanation

The Class Contains

```
/**
* Constructor. Initializes a database connection and selects our database.
* @param string $host       The host to wchich to connect.
* @param string $username   The name of the user used to login to the database.
* @param string $password   The password of the user to login to the database.
* @param string $database   The name of the database to which to connect.
*/
function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
{
    $this->DB_HOST     = $host;
    $this->DB_USERNAME = $username;
    $this->DB_PASSWORD = $password;
    $this->DB_DATABASE = $database;
}
```

what you need in your PHP code is something like this

```
$db = new DbConnect("localhost","username","password","database");
```

It is a `bad practice` trying to hard-code values directly in a class what if you need to connect to multiple `host` or `database`

**Joe Burnett**

As a beginner you don't need such classes when MySQL as fantastic `mysqli' extension which is also object oriented and very fast .

The usage is similar to what you have not but does not require any additional including any class

Example

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");
```

Fore more information and examples see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: I don't believe that you should create an entire class just to connect to a MySQL database, when it can be done in one simple line of code.

Comment: @Joe Burnett ... valid point but A. ` I find myself very very stupidly blocked because I am unable to understand` He needs to understand how to use the class B. Sometimes you might need a `mysql` or extend `mysql` for some flexibility .. example `$mysql->getSUM()` etc ...

Comment: @Baba... I completely agree, but from the askers stand point (a beginner) he most-likely will only need basic functionality.

Comment: +1 for another good point .. i would update my answer .. with your suggestion

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

I will say that that was the longest MySQL connect script I have ever seen, but here you go...

```
function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        $this->DB_HOST     = "HostName";
        $this->DB_USERNAME = "username";
        $this->DB_PASSWORD = "password";
        $this->DB_DATABASE = "database";
    }
```

Find that function in your code and edit its contents. Put your information inside the "".